# How to set global variable from XML response

Tags: xml, postman, postman-pre-request-script

Im trying to set global variable `sessionId` from the XML response. I tried below code:

```
var responseJson = xml2Json(responseBody);
console.log(responseJson);
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("sessionID", responseJson.Envelope.Body.CreateSessionResponse.CreateSessionResult.Output.sessionID);
```

But its returning error:

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Body').

**Heres how the JSON structure looks like from the response XML:**

[image: Please click on this image to see the json structure]

**Here is my response XML:**

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <CreateSessionResponse xmlns="http://vz.com/Anywhere/Service/v9">
            <CreateSessionResult>
                <output>
                    <sessionId>azrsit-2fb658dc-7048-4188-8427</sessionId>
                </output>
            </CreateSessionResult>
        </CreateSessionResponse>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Comment: Check the status in the responseJson and see if it is 200 OK.

Comment: yes its is 200 OK

Comment: how do reproduce your problem? Any method to get your responseBody?

Comment: Does you response body byte count greater than zero?

Comment: I have added response XML in question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1.  Using xml2Json and bracket notation to target the elements due to some of the elements using special characters.

```js
let responseJson = xml2Json(responseBody);

let sessionId = responseJson["s:Envelope"]["s:Body"]["CreateSessionResponse"]["CreateSessionResult"]["output"]["sessionId"];

console.log(sessionId);
```

If you struggle to target an element, start at the top and console log it one level at at time until you hit the intended target.

Option 2.  Using xml2js to remove all of the name space info, making it easier to target the elements.

```js
let respBodyXML = pm.response.text();
let parseString = require('xml2js').parseString;
let stripPrefix = require('xml2js').processors.stripPrefix;

parseString(respBodyXML, {
    tagNameProcessors: [stripPrefix], //removing prefix
    ignoreAttrs: true, //ignoring all attributes including xmlns
    explicitArray: false,
    explicitRoot: true//including root tag inside the JSON
}, function (err, result) {
    console.log(result);
    console.log(result.Envelope.Body.CreateSessionResponse.CreateSessionResult.output.sessionId);
});
```

[image]

Comment: Option 1 worked! I was using dot notation and it wasnt working. Now I know if I need to deal with special character I need bracket notation